# MySQL Union All in Yii's default scope

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.16, and was wondering how would i  Union 2 model's using the default scope?

```
model 1 = abc
model 2 = abc2
```

basically i want to do a simple union

```
SELECT * FROM `abc`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `abc2`
```

Havent really used default scope, so kind of new to the concept. **Both tables have the exact same column numbers and column names.**

i tried this, but failed.

in my `abc` model

```
public function defaultScope() {
        return array(
            'alias' => 't2',
            'select'=>array('t.*, t2.*'),
            'union'=>array('SELECT * FROM `abc2`')
        );
    }
```

**UPDATE:** 
Just realized `http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria`, there is NO `union` for `CDbCriteria`.

```
public function defaultScope() {
        return array(
            //'alias' => 't',
            'select'=>array('*'),
            'join'=>'UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `abc2`'
        );
    }
```

code above gives me an error

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.make_code' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`class_code`, `t`.`make_code`, `t`.`model_code` FROM `abc` `t` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `abc2` WHERE `t`.`make_code`=:yp0 LIMIT 1. Bound with :yp0='11'
```

in both tables, i have the column `make_code`

I need the query to look like this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM `abc` 
      UNION ALL 
   SELECT * FROM `abc2`
) AS t
```

how to go about this?

Comment: yeah, kind of found this. but still trying to figure it out `http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/486/defaultscope/`

Comment: Please explain what entities do you have? And why do you want to use 1 AR model for 2 db tables?

Comment: @AlexAkr coz  1 table has info of new products and 1 has used. i know i can just merge them both into 1 table and tag them as new and used. (which would be simpler) unfortunately the 2 tables are updated frequently and they are given to us ever few weeks in a CD. i would like to just update the mysql as is

Comment: hi @user2636556 , if you tell me what am i missing in my answer i could fix it or finish helping you out with this, i really think the answer for this question is here , regards

Comment: @DiegoCoderPlus dont quite get what you are trying to do actually :( i just want a way where if i do `Abc::model()->findAll()` i get the results of both tables union'd together

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Yii [query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder); it's the go-to solution when you need to build non-standard queries, and it natively supports `UNION`:

```
$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
  ->select('*')
  ->from('abc')
  ->union('SELECT * FROM `abc2`')
  ->where('make_code=:make_code', [':make_code'=>42])
  ->queryAll();
```

Alternatively, instead of directly querying you can use `->getText()` or write the SQL manually and then utilize [`CSqlDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider) to make a configurable data source.

Comment: so there is no way for it to be used in `defaultScope()`? Everytime i call the model `abc` i have to have a custom function that does the union and call that?

Comment: @user2636556: There is no way. `defaultScope` is fed into `CDbCriteria`, and you can see in the docs that class has no provision for supporting union selects.

Answer (score 2):

Hello i hope i can help you out , 
right now cdbcriteria of yii 1.x is not ready for unions... so i think more on other solutions or wa.

so, the easy way to get around this is to create a view from the query you need wich is:

```
CREATE VIEW unionAbc AS
SELECT * FROM `abc` 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM `abc2`
```

then from that view you can construct a new model and call it with out much effort.

the other solution i have found is to merge model queries result, this i am telling you from a php theory perspective, what i mean is that when you generate a model query in yii it is returning either and a array or object, you will need to use array converters from model that exist in yii helper and then merge both arrays so it will result in a new one with both info

third solution not tested would be:

```
$dataProvider =  new CArrayDataProvider('User');
$dataProvider->setData($modelabc->findAll());
$dataProvider->setData($modelabc2->findAll());
```

regards.

Comment: so anytime i have an update to the `abc` or `abc2` tables i have to go to phpmyadmin and create view `unionAbc` ?

Comment: not at all, the view is created just once, then it behave following the query you introduced in its creation...

Answer (score 2):

i suggest KISS solution : 
is it possible create view from union select and work with it?

and then create Active Record from this view.

 of course for Create/Remove data in UI, you must create model separately in both table. 
 
**Update**
you can create view in data base : 
`CREATE VIEW abc_union AS
SELECT * FROM abc
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM abc2` 
and then generate model with Gii for this view.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have 2 equal tables in the DB, may be it will be better to gather them into one. Yii's ActiveRecord realization based on the simple rule: one table -> one active record model.

I suggest you this solution using repository pattern. I don't think that usage of `defaultScope()` is essential.

1.Create an interface to ensure both product models implement some common methods.

```
interface Product
{
    public function findAllByMakeCode($makeCode);

    // other common methods here
}
```

2.Create a trait with common methods implementation or default scope you need.

```
trait ProductTrait
{
    function findAllByMakeCode($makeCode)
    {
        return $this->model()->findAllByAttributes(['make_code' => $makeCode]);
    }

    function defaultScope()
    {
        // your default scope condition
        // for example field is_deleted equals to 0
        return ['condition' => 'is_deleted=0'];
    }
    // other common methods implementation
}
```

3.Create separate AR models for both tables.

```
// used product entity
class ProductUsed extends CActiveRecord implements Product
{
    use ProductTrait;

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'product_used';
    }
}

// new product entity
class ProductNew extends CActiveRecord implements Product
{
    use ProductTrait;

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'product_new';
    }
}
```

4.Create a Repository class.

```
class ProductRepository
{   
    public function findAllByMakeCode($makeCode)
    {
        return array_merge(
            ProductUsed::model()->findAllByMakeCode($makeCode),
            ProductNew::model()->findAllByMakeCode($makeCode)
        );
    }

    public function findAll($condition = '', array $params = [])
    {
        return array_merge(
            ProductUsed::model()->findAll($condition = '', array $params = []),
            ProductNew::model()->findAll($condition = '', array $params = [])
        );
    }
}
```

5.Use it.

```
$repository = new ProductRepository();

// all products
$products = $repository->findAll();

// products with 42 make code
$products42 = $repository->findAllByMakeCode(42);
```

Maybe it looks little bit complex, but it's worth it.

Comment: the `$makeCode` is a condition i add later "when needed" not part of the `defaultScope()` can it still be done?

Comment: Sure, you can add a default scope for both your models in ProductTrait. The answer was updated. By the way, the main purpose of default scope is to filter table rows by some condition (ex. `is_deleted` flag unsettled) not for `union`, `join`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can make **UNION** like this;

```
$firtQuery = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select("*")
    ->from('abc')
    //->where() you can add WHERE clause in here
    ->getText();

$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select("*")
    ->from('abc2')
    //->where() you can add WHERE clause in here
    ->union($firtQuery)
    ->queryRow();
```

Comment: how would i make it the default query for the model? so anytime `$a=new Abc;` is called, it's already a union?